# Primefaces datatable disapeares after update from commandLink

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

when i try to update the `datatable` from a `comandLink` on the first time it works fine, However on the second time the `datatable` disapeares yet i still see the paginator.

here is the datatable code :

```xhtml
<p:dataTable id="tabexam"
             paginatorPosition="bottom"
             var="exam"
             value="#{dyna.examViewDataModel}"
             widgetVar="examTable"
             emptyMessage="aucun résultat trouvé pour votre recherche"
             paginator="true"
             rows="40" 
             selection="#{dyna.selectedExamen}"
             selectionMode="single"
             resizableColumns="true"  
             draggableColumns="true"
             paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
             rowsPerPageTemplate="40,80,120"
             rowStyleClass="#{exam.studyWithRv_1 == 0 ? 'RV' : exam.studyUrgence == 1 ? 'Urgent' : null}">
```

```xhtml
   <p:column>
         <p:outputLabel value="#{column.dbname}"  styleClass="fonty"/>
   </p:column>
 </p:columns>  
</p:datatable>
```

this is the command link code :

```xhtml
<ui:repeat var="list" value="#{dyna.userlist}" varStatus="loop">

    <center>
      <p:commandLink id="listerlink"
                     title="Afficher la liste"
                     actionListener="#{datatableBean.updatecolumns(list.id.tbCode)}"
                     update=":form1:tabexam,:form1:msg,:form1:displaycols">
         <p:graphicImage id="imglist"  value="/images/Liste_Cold.png"/><br></br>
         <p:outputLabel value="#{list.id.tbCode}"/><br></br>

      </p:commandLink>
     </center>

</ui:repeat>
```

***Additional Info:***

No Nested forms.

Using p:Layout.

Beans Scope : ViewScoped.

Everything works fine when draggableColumns="false".

what possibly i could be missing ?

Comment: Probably a JS issue. Try with a more basic datatable and see if the same happens to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have changed `<p:commandLink>` with `<h:commandLink>` and it works like a charm.